# html create "checkbox-like" layout without checkmark (razor)

Tags: html, razor

I am trying to create this layout:

[image]

the user can select one or multiple items from this list:

[image]

```
<table class="itemBackgrond centered" id="@elem.CategoryId"> @*give it id as cat name*@
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p>
                @elem.Title
            </p>
            <input style="display: none;" type="text" value="" name="selectedIdentifier"  class="@elem.CategoryId" /> @
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img class="imgSmall" src="@elem.ImageSource" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I achieved this working with my own logic and creating my own layouts for everything, but I would much rather have those be checkboxes that just look a little different.

They dont have a checkmark, and if they are checked they change the background color.
Also I need text and images inside the checkbox.

I was wondering if this is even achievable, or if I should maybe go another way.

What is your recomendation to create a list with items like this and multiple choice but not creating a whole own logic but rather stick to framework material?

thank you

Comment: This is a frontend issue and I would solve it in the front either with CSS or with JS not in the backend with C#. The easiest way would be the usage of `<input>` type checkbox where you hide the input with CSS. The Item itself is placed inside the label which you can style differently if the input is checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already stated in the comment, this is a Frontend issue and should be solved in the Frontend not with C#, respectively Razor.

## non-JS Solution

You can solve this with pure HTML and CSS which Markupwise is not correct and overall not the cleanest solution (also not necessarily the most accessible one). However, you would not require JS for it.

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

label {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 1em;
  height: 10em;
  width: 10em;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
  background-color: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="BauUndHandwerk">
<label for="BauUndHandwerk">Bau und Handwerk</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="BeratungUndCoaching">
<label for="BeratungUndCoaching">Beratung & Coaching</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="EinkaufUndVertrieb">
<label for="EinkaufUndVertrieb">Einkauf & Vertrieb</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="Einzelhandel">
<label for="Einzelhandel">Einzelhandel</label>
```

This works because you hide the checkbox in CSS by using `display: none` in the CSS. Then the cards themself are the labels connected to the input. In CSS you can use the `+` combinator to change the label color when the checkbox is checked.

## JS Solution

The JS solution is cleaner. It basically works by adding an `eventListener` to the cards and toggling a CSS class.

```js
const ELEMENTS = document.querySelectorAll('div');

ELEMENTS.forEach(element => 
  element.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.target.classList.toggle('checked');
  })
);
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 1em;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  height: 10em;
  width: 10em;
}

.checked {
  background-color: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<div>Bau und Handwerk</div>
<div>Beratung & Coaching</div>
<div>Einkauf & Vertrieb</div>
<div>Einzelhandel</div>
```

You select all elements with `document.querySelectorAll()` which will return a Node List. Then you iterate over the Node List with `forEach` and add an `eventListener` to it. Then you can use the event delegation to toggle a class with `classList.toggle()`

Comment: Thank you very much! this was EXACTLY what I was looking for! You sir are a gentleman and a scholar!